# UWP PivotItem Header visibility binding

Tags: c#, uwp, mvvmcross

I'm doing a binding in UWP, the listview is not showing(so it's working fine), but the header is still on the view.

So the problem is that the header is not getting the binding from the PivotItem, what can be the problem?

```
<PivotItem Header="Hello" Visibility="{Binding isVisible, Converter={StaticResource Visibility}}">
    <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myList}"/>
</PivotItem>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is actually a bit tricky. Setting `Visibility` on a `PivotItem` does indeed hide only the contents of the item, not the `PivotItem` itself. That said, you can hide it from the code-behind by removing it from the pivot completely:

```
MyPivot.Items.Remove(HideablePivotItem);
```

The problem is now the fact that you need to trigger it on binding change. For that purpose I suggest you use a custom `Behavior` and a `CallMethodAction`.

First install the `Microsoft.Xaml.Behaviors.Uwp.Managed` from NuGet (right-click your project, click `Manage NuGet Packages...` find the package using search and click `Install`.

Now, create a new class `DataChangeTriggerBehavior` class:

```
public class DataChangeTriggerBehavior : Trigger<FrameworkElement>
{
    public static readonly DependencyProperty BindingProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
        nameof(Binding), typeof(object), typeof(DataChangeTriggerBehavior), new PropertyMetadata(null, BindingChanged));

    public object Binding
    {
        get => (object)GetValue(BindingProperty);
        set => SetValue(BindingProperty, value);
    }

    private static void BindingChanged(DependencyObject dependencyObject, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args)
    {
        DataChangeTriggerBehavior changeTrigger = (DataChangeTriggerBehavior)dependencyObject;

        if (changeTrigger.AssociatedObject == null) return;

        Interaction.ExecuteActions(changeTrigger.AssociatedObject, changeTrigger.Actions, args);
    }
}
```

This behavior will observe a binding and trigger its associated actions whenever the binding changes.

Now, update your `Page` element as follows:

```
<Page 
    ...
    x:Name="Page"
    xmlns:interactivity="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactivity"
    xmlns:core="using:Microsoft.Xaml.Interactions.Core"
    xmlns:customBehavior="using:XXX"
    mc:Ignorable="d">
```

Where `XXX` is the namespace where your behavior is defined.

Now use the behavior in your `Pivot`:

```
<Pivot x:Name="MyPivot">
    <interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
        <local:DataChangeTriggerBehavior Binding="{Binding isVisible}">
            <core:CallMethodAction MethodName="TogglePivotItem" 
                                   TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=Page}" />
        </local:DataChangeTriggerBehavior>
    </interactivity:Interaction.Behaviors>
    <PivotItem Header="Hello" Visibility="Collapsed" x:Name="HideablePivotItem">
        <ListView ItemsSource="{Binding myList}"/>
    </PivotItem>
</Pivot>
```

Finally you must define the `TogglePivotItem` method in your page's code-behind:

```
private int originalPosition = 0;

public void TogglePivotItem()
{
    if (MyPivot.Items.Contains(HideablePivotItem))
    {
        //store the position of the item to be readded later
        originalPosition = MyPivot.Items.IndexOf(HideablePivotItem);
        MyPivot.Items.Remove(HideablePivotItem);
    }
    else
    {
        MyPivot.Items.Insert(originalPosition, HideablePivotItem);
    }            
}
```

I am storing the original position of the `PivotItem` so that it can be re-added to the same place again.

Comment: Very glad it helped :-) . And I thank you for the nice question! Happy coding :-)